# How do we set x-www-form-urlencoded type body in jenkins pipeline/groovy post request?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

def body ='{"1":"ab","2":"cd"}'

def response = httpRequest(httpMode: 'POST', url: "https://***/xyz",
customHeaders:[[name:"Content-type",value:"application/x-wwww-form-urlencoded"]],
**body =body**)

Expected response is json values.Here always received Html page.

IN Postman, when we choose body type is x-wwww-form-urlencoded , we are getting correct json format response.
IN Postman, when we choose any other body type/no body , we are getting html formatted output.

```
      How do we achieve similar json output via jenkins/groovy script?
```

genkins website content :::  *requestBody : String (optional)
The **raw body** of the request.*

```
   How do we set x-wwww-form-urlencoded type body in jenkins post request?
```

Comment: Have you found the solution yet?

Answer (score 2):

```
def response = httpRequest(
  contentType: 'APPLICATION_FORM',
  httpMode: 'POST',
  customHeaders: [whatever]
  requestBody: 'MyVariableOne=ValueOne&MyVariableTwo=ValueTwo...',
  url: 'https://whatever'
)
println(response.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

As has said [Alex Popov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20223467/alex-popov) in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74044079/3131022), you can simply use :
`contentType: 'APPLICATION_FORM'`

But, actually, `APPLICATION_FORM` is defined with `org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED` ([http_request - MimeType.java#L15](https://github.com/jenkinsci/http-request-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/jenkins/plugins/http_request/MimeType.java#L15))

So, you'll ends with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1` ([apache httpcomponents contenttype](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-core/blob/master/httpcore5/src/main/java/org/apache/hc/core5/http/ContentType.java#L73)

It shouldn't be a problem, but, if you want to restrict your Content-Type HTTP header, you can overwrite it using:

```
customHeaders: [
  [name: "header1", value: "value1"],
  ...
  [name: "Content-Type", value: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"],
  ...
  [name: "headerN", value: "valueN"]
]
```